# MongoDB: $geoNear aggregation returns an empty array

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm following a Mongoose tutorial I did everything as the tutor did, but I get an empty array when I use $geoNear aggregation.

The request handler

```
exports.getDistances = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { latlang, unit } = req.params;
  const [lat, lang] = latlang.split(',');

  const multiplier = unit === 'mi' ? 0.000621371 : 0.001

  if (!lat || !lang) {
    next(
      new AppError(
        'Please provide latitude and longitude in format: lat,lang',
        400
      )
    );
  }

  const distances = await Tour.aggregate([
    {
      $geoNear: {
         near: {type: "Point", coordinates: [lang * 1, lat * 1  ]}  ,
         distanceField: "distance",
         distanceMultiplier: multiplier 
      },
      $project: {
        distance: 1,
        name: 1
      }
    }
  ])

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    results: distances.length,
    data: {
      data: distances,
    },
  });
});
```

And here is the index

```
tourSchema.index({startLoaction: '2dsphere'})
```

Although the aggregation doesn't work even using MongoDB compass

Comment: Well, do you have any data in your 'tours' collection?

Comment: yes, of course I and here is the schema field  startLocation: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Point'],
        default: 'Point',
      },
      coordinates: [Number],
      address: String,
      description: String,
    },

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.